# Replacing CMNewProfileSearch with non-deprecated, 64-bit code

Tags: cocoa, macos, macos-carbon

I have existing code that uses `CMNewProfileSearch` to find then iterate over the color profiles on the system getting their names and full paths.  Unfortunately, `CMNewProfileSearch` is deprecated in Mac OS X 10.5 and is also unavailable when compiling a 64-bit application.

In reading the ColorSync Manager 2.5 Reference, it seems like the new way to iterate over installed color profiles is to use the `CMIterateColorSyncFolder` function.

1. Is that true?
2. Is there a Cocoa way to do what I want instead?
3. Anybody got any sample code?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes. As you indicated, the [ColorSync Manager Reference](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/graphicsimaging/Reference/ColorSync_Manager/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html) says the following:

   The CMNewProfileSearch function does not take full advantage of the optimized profile
   searching available starting with ColorSync version 2.5. Use CMIterateColorSyncFolder
   instead.
2. `CMIterateColorSyncFolder` is the *official* way to do this.  Besides, it's also the *optimized* way.
3. From [Apple's ImageApp sample code](http://developer.apple.com/SampleCode/ImageApp/listing16.html):

EDIT: I've modified the code sample to remove `NewCMProfileIterateUPP` and `DisposeCMProfileIterateUPP`.

```
    // Callback routine with a description of a profile that is 
    // called during an iteration through the available profiles.
    //
    static OSErr profileIterate (CMProfileIterateData *info, void *refCon)
    {
        NSMutableArray* array = (NSMutableArray*) refCon;

        Profile* prof = [Profile profileWithIterateData:info];
        if (prof)
            [array addObject:prof];

        return noErr;
    }

    // return an array of all profiles
    //
    + (NSArray*) arrayOfAllProfiles
    {
        NSMutableArray* profs=[[NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:0] retain];
        CMIterateColorSyncFolder(profileIterate, NULL, 0L, profs);
        return (NSArray*)profs;
    }
```

It turns out that don't need `NewCMProfileIterateUPP` and `DisposeCMProfileIterateUPP` so they haven't been replaced with anything, as far as I can tell. Instead, you can define the callback function with a signature that matches `profileIterate`, above. You can then just pass the callback function directly to `CMIterateColorSyncFolder`.

I've tested my changes in [ImageApp](http://developer.apple.com/SampleCode/ImageApp/index.html) on Mac OS X 10.5 it it works as expected.

Comment: The functions NewCMProfileIterateUPP() and DisposeCMProfileIterateUPP() are deprecated in Mac OS X 10.5.

Comment: Good point.  I've edited the code sample so that NewCMProfileIterateUPP() and DisposeCMProfileIterateUPP() are no longer used.  Hopefully that answers everything for you. ;)

Comment: Hi, I know this question was posted long time back. But I am working in a similar problem and CMIterateColorSyncFolder is now depreciated. Is there any alternatives for it ?