# Deprecated ColorSync Manager Functions

Tags: objective-c, colors, quartz-core

The ColorSync Manager functions was deprecated. 
Where to find the solution to deal with about icc profile.

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/822945/replacing-cmnewprofilesearch-with-non-deprecated-64-bit-code

Comment: @NikosM.: That question and its answer are from 2009, and do not cover the fact that *all* ColorSync Manager functions are marked deprecated starting with Mac OS X 10.6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All ColorSync Manager function are deprecated since Mac OS X 10.6 (see https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/ColorSync_Manager/Reference/reference.html). As far as I know:

- All ColorSync functions are still available up to OS X 10.9.
  The reason is probably that many applications depend on this functionality.
- There is no other Apple framework replacing ColorSync. Core Graphics allows you to
  perform certain color transformations, but does not offer the full functionality of Color Sync.

We can only hope that Apple provides a replacement before removing the deprecated 
functions from OS X.

If you don't want to depend on a deprecated interface, then
perhaps "Little CMS" (http://www.littlecms.com) could be an alternative (*you* know
about it :-), but I have no practical experience with that.