# How do I find display profiles now that everything in the ColorSync Manager API is deprecated

Tags: macos, cocoa, deprecated, color-management

I'm upgrading an OS X app that's been using the [ColorSync Manager API](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/ColorSync_Manager/index.html) to fetch color profiles for attached displays. The writing was on the wall circa OS X 10.6, when everything in the API was marked deprecated. For a long while, it was still possible to `#include <ColorSyncDeprecated.h>`, but in the most recent SDKs that isn't possible any more.

The app already uses Little CMS to actually manipulate color spaces, so I don't need much. As I noted above, the only thing it uses ColorSync for is to get the profile of the primary display using `CMGetSystemProfile` and `NCMGetProfileLocation`.

There are a couple of Questions that are somewhat related to this, but they're a few years old now and don't solve the problem:

- [Deprecated ColorSync Manager Functions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19708563/733626): suggests using Little CMS to deal with color management; offers no alternative for finding System profiles.
- [Replacing CMNewProfileSearch with non-deprecated, 64-bit code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/822945/733626): asked six years ago, in 2009; recommends using functions that are now also deprecated.

Is there ***any*** alternative to this now in any OS X Framework, or has Apple just decided that no one should ever want to know the profile of their display?

Answer (score 2):

```
The new ColorSync API is defined in
/System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Frameworks/ColorSync.framework/Headers

in
    ColorSync.h
    ColorSyncBase.h
    ColorSyncCMM.h
    ColorSyncDeprecated.h
    ColorSyncDevice.h
    ColorSyncProfile.h
    ColorSyncTransform.h

and wasn't documented anywhere by Apple the last time I looked.
```

They seem to have forgotten to declare

```
CFUUIDRef CGDisplayCreateUUIDFromDisplayID (uint32_t displayID);
```

as well.

I didn't find any means of determining the locations of profiles using current OS X API's, so had to hard code them:

```
#define COLORSYNC_DIR_NETWORK   "/Network/Library/ColorSync/Profiles/"
#define COLORSYNC_DIR_SYSTEM    "/System/Library/ColorSync/Profiles/"
#define COLORSYNC_DIR_LOCAL     "/Library/ColorSync/Profiles/"
#define COLORSYNC_DIR_USER      "/Library/ColorSync/Profiles/"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use CoreGraphice API

```
colorSpace = ::CGDisplayCopyColorSpace(::CGMainDisplayID());
```

then, with api likes:

```
CGColorSpaceCopyICCData
```

you can do some color sync things. I think this is most likely what you want do with old ColorSync API.

Comment: That looks promising — thanks! I no longer have Xcode on a Mac handy to try it out. I'll upvote your answer right now, and accept it when I've had a chance to confirm it works.

Answer (score 1):

Apple's current documentation pages do not mark ColorSync Manager as deprecated. Some data types and methods are, but most of it has no such indication. Perhaps it has been 'precated'?

[ColorSync Manager pages](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/applicationservices/colorsync_manager?language=objc)

Answer (score 0):

This is what I am doing to get the profile path for a known direct display ID.

1. include the new ColorSync framework, since 10.13 it is not in ApplicationServices anymore
2. convert display ID to UUID using CGDisplayCreateUUIDFromDisplayID
3. call ColorSyncIterateDeviceProfiles with a callback
4. the callback will be called for every device, and you will get a dictionary as a parameter with info on the device, UUID, URL, name, ...
5. I compare my UUID with the UUID in the dictionary, if I found a match, I copy the URL from the dictionary and return false to stop iteration, if not I return true to get the callback for the next device